# Android application and read the web page

Tags: delphi

I have a question about the webbrowser component
 Sow you change platform (mobile) devices  note opens page

Display
Page Web note fond

Android path :Assets\internal\

thanks

EDIT: Code from comment

```
Var MS:tmemorystream; 

Begin 
  Ms:=tmemorystream.create; 
  Ms.loadfromfile(gethomepath+pathdelim+'name.html'); 
  Ms.postion:=0; 
  Ms.savetofile(opendilog .filename); 
  Webbrowser.navigate(opendilog.filename or 'name.html');
end;
```

Comment: Var
MS:tmemorystream;
Begin
Ms:=tmemorystream.create;
Ms.loadfromfile(gethomepath+pathdelim+'name.html');
Ms.postion:=0;
Ms.savetofile(opendilog .filename);
Webbrowser .navigate(opendilog.filename or 'name.html');

Comment: Why don't you load the web page directly from the original file path? Why are you loading the original file into TMemoryStrem just so that you later save it to a new file? PS: I have edited your question to include the code that you have posted in your comment. You should have edited the question yourself to include that information in it.

Comment: The app has in mobile you cant connect live you add in assets after call the fille

Answer (score 2):

`assets\internal` is not a path that your device can access. It's a path setting used by the deployment manager. To properly access that folder you must use

```
System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath
```

which points to the same folder that `assets\internal` points to.

The documentation for that is here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms